# Erro socket.io Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

A intenção com o programa é que quando dois clientes se conectarem exibir na janela de um cliente o id do outro. O programa salva os dois ids nas variaveis mas envia apenas para o primeiro usuario que se conectou. O segundo usuario conectado não recebe nada.

arquivo do servidor:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

var userOne = 0;
var userTwo = 0;

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected');
    if (userOne == 0){
        userOne = socket.id;
        console.log('id1:' + userOne);
    }else{
        userTwo = socket.id;
        console.log('id2:' + userTwo);
        socket.to(userOne).emit('saveId', userTwo);
        socket.to(userTwo).emit('saveId', userOne);
    }

    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        io.emit('chat message', msg);
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });
    socket.send(socket.id);
});


http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

arquivo cliente:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
        * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
        body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
        form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
        form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
        form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
        #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
        #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
        #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
        <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>

    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>
        var idConect = 0;
        $('#messages').append($('<li>').text('Conectado ao id:' + idConect));
        $(function () {
            var socket = io();
            $('form').submit(function(){
                socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
                $('#m').val('');
                return false;
            });
            socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
                $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
            });

            socket.on('saveId', function(id){
                idConect = id;
                $('#messages').append($('<li>').text('Conectado ao id:' + idConect));
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Você pode incluir seu código completo?

Comment: Editei o post com o código completo, fiz uma adaptação no código que encontrei no próprio site do  socket.io. Estou tentando fazer com que dois clientes interajam entre si.

Answer (score 2):

Edite sua conexão adicionando o broadcast:

```
io.on("connection", function (socket) {
  socket.on("join", function(name){
    console.log("Entrou: " + name);
    clients[socket.id] = name; //id do user
    socket.emit('chat message', "Você se conectou no servidor.");
    socket.broadcast.emit('chat message', name + " acabou de entrar no chat.")
  });
```

Há uma diferença entre o método `socket.emit` e o `socket.broadcast.emit`. O `socket.emit` enviará a notificação somente para o cliente atual, ou seja, o cliente que acabou de entrar na sala de chat. O `socket.broadcast.emit` irá emitir para **todos os clientes conectados**, com exceção de quem está enviando.

Exemplos de métodos disponíveis:

```
// enviar apenas para o cliente atual
socket.emit('message', "this is a test");

// enviar para todos os clientes, inclusive o atual
io.emit('message', "this is a test");

// enviar para todos os clientes, exceto o atual
socket.broadcast.emit('message', "this is a test");

// enviar para todos os clientes (com exceção do atual) para uma sala específica
socket.broadcast.to('game').emit('message', 'nice game');

// enviar para todos os clientes em uma sala específica
io.in('game').emit('message', 'cool game');

// enviar para o atual, caso ele esteja na sala
socket.to('game').emit('message', 'enjoy the game');

// enviar para todos os clientes em um namespace 'namespace1'
io.of('namespace1').emit('message', 'gg');

// enviando para um socketid individual
socket.broadcast.to(socketid).emit('message', 'for your eyes only');
```

Realmente recomendo [este site](https://tableless.com.br/criando-uma-aplicacao-de-chat-simples-com-nodejs-e-socket-io/) para um exemplo real do uso de `socket.io`